# How do I order the bars of a bar chart by height rather than alphabetically

Tags: sas, bar-chart

Here's a simple data set:

```
data dat;

  do i = 1 to 100;

     if      rand('unif') > 0.85 then txt = 'DEFG';
     else if rand('unif') > 0.75 then txt = 'ABC';
     else if rand('unif') > 0.80 then txt = 'KLMNOP';
     else                             txt = 'HIJ';

     output;
  end;

run;
```

I want to create a bar chart that displays the frequencies of `txt`:

```
proc sgplot data = dat;
/* Bars are ordered alphabetically */
   vbar txt;
run;
```

This creates [image: this image]

What I'd like instead is to order the bars by height (from left to right: HIJ, ABC, DEFG, KLMN).

Is there an option to `proc sgplot` to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add option **categoryorder** in your vbar statement:

```
proc sgplot data = dat;
   vbar txt /categoryorder=respdesc ;
run; quit;
```

I found it here: http://blogs.sas.com/content/graphicallyspeaking/2012/06/07/bar-chart-with-response-sort/#prettyPhoto
[image]